# What does "honking" mean in this context?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

[Joel Spolsky](http://www.businessinsider.com/exclusive-qa-quora-may-be-turning-down-billion-dollar-offers-but-its-still-losing-to-this-guy-2011-2?IR=T&):

> We started with Stack Overflow, a Q&A site for programmers about
>   programming questions. StackExchange is an attempt to bring that same
>   technology to other fields besides programming. Cooking, photography,
>   etc. Each of these sites is a StackExchange. Collectively they are the
>   StackExchange Network. **So when we say "StackExchange" we mean all
>   these sites, of which there is one big honking granddaddy called Stack
>   Overflow.**

The [entries in Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/honking) suggest that *honking* refers to an object making a loud noise, but that meaning seems off in this context.

What does "honking" mean in this context?

Comment: I think this is General Reference - [**honking**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=honking) *- anything large, excessive, or otherwise inordinately disproportionate by almost any measure.* Though for me as a Brit, *honk* is primarily a verb meaning *to vomit*, so in OP's context I would use [**stonking**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/stonking).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually separated, if you look at the whole phrase. **"Big honking [x]"** is a colloquial way of saying *very big [x]*. *Granddaddy*, in this sense, just means that it is the precursor to the entire Stack Exchange (Stack Overflow was the original).

Comment: Hmm, weird, dictionary.com do list colloquial entries too, but doesn't seem to have this entry http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/honking

Comment: As a native speaker of SAE, I've always used/heard it said without the trailing velar nasal, as *honkin'*.

Comment: Btw, is there a (online or not) dictionary that lists *honking* as "big"?

Comment: @Pacerier - That's a good honking question! I don't think _honking_ means "big" as much as it means "ol'", as in "big honking truck" = "big ol' truck". I like how the Urban Dictionary defines **big ol'**: _A phrase tapped onto a noun giving the object in question more significance, or importance. The object in question does not need to be relatively big or old._ In this context, _honking_ could even be regarded as a nice way to say _f-ing_.

Comment: What J.R. said plus "honking" is not usually left on its own to fill in for "big" and "ol'".  It's much more idiomatic (here in the US) to see/hear ***"big ol' honking X"***

Comment: @Pacerier OneLook.com provides about 20 definitions, the only one for _big_ is http://www.waywordradio.org/honking/, make of that what you will. Urban Dictionary as General Reference ? ... yeah, if you really can't guess what _poopsterbate_ means.

Answer (score 1):

'Honking' refers to winding around and in this case of 
***...of which there is one big honking granddaddy***, it signifies the object to which all others are wound upon.

'Honking' is a term used in watchmaking:

> .... a small steel chain is **honked** to the spring-barrel, it, (fig.
>   1 and 5) ; at one end it passes round the barrel several times -British encyclopedia; or, Dictionary of arts and ... v.12. Nicholson, William, 1753-1815.

Comment: I think in this case it's a slang intensifier, not a technical/archaic term for winding.